# Extract Captivate 4 text captions using Flex (ActionScript 3)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe-captivate

I'm developing an application in Flex 3.5 for video tutorials, which uses a lot of Captivate 4 (AS3) videos (>200). In the front end, the user can navigate thorough the videos in a menu structure. In the administration part, the admins can upload more videos and organize them into the menu structure. Since we have more than 200 Captivate videos, we wanted to build in a search functionality into the fronted, which would be based on the text contents of the Captivate videos. The idea is: every time the admin uploads a new Captivate video into the system, an index will be created based on the contents of the video.

**My question: how can I extract the text captions of a Captivate video using Flex or rather ActionScrip 3?**

(I know, there is an Export/Import function of Captivate, but I would like to access those texts dynamically from Flex.)

I appreciate your help.

Regards,
Tas

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off doing the extraction server side?

Comment: Well... my problem is *how* to extract the text data... whether I do it server side or not, it's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the answer. Every Captivate video (at least Captivate 4) has a variable called **movieXML**. After loading a Captivate video in Flex with flash.display.Loader or URLLoader, you can access this variable and extract all the information you need.

Greetings,
 Tas